# Coffeescript class mixin not working for constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, coffeescript, mixins

I have two base classes which look like this (significantly simplified for this example):

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@foo) ->

class Bar
  constructor: (@bar) ->
```

Then I have two further classes that extend / enhance these classes by extending them and adding features:

```
class NewFoo extends Foo
  getFoo: ->
    @foo

class NewBar extends Bar
  getBar: ->
    @bar
```

However, I would also like NewFoo and NewBar to inherit a common constructor / other method e.g.

```
class Mixin
  constructor: (x) ->
    @history = 'something'
    super x

  getHistory: ->
    @history
```

I am trying to get NewFoo and NewBar to have the Mixin constructor and getHistory method..

I tried with the coffeescriptcookbook mixin example: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/classes_and_objects/mixins

```
mixOf = (base, mixins...) ->
  class Mixed extends base
  for mixin in mixins by -1 #earlier mixins override later ones
    for name, method of mixin::
      Mixed::[name] = method
  Mixed
```

So NewFoo / NewBar become:

```
class NewFoo extends mixOf Mixin, Foo
  getFoo: ->
    @foo

class NewBar extends mixOf Mixin, Bar
  getBar: ->
    @bar
```

However this doesn't work and fails with the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

How can I get NewFoo / NewBar to inherit the common Mixin members as well as their respective base classes?

Edit:

This is all I have been able to come up with so far:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@foo) ->

class Bar
  constructor: (@bar) ->

history = (base) ->
  class History extends base
    constructor: (param) ->
      @history = 'something'
      super param

    getHistory: ->
      @history
  History

class NewFoo extends history Foo
  getFoo: ->
    @foo

class NewBar extends history Bar
  getBar: ->
    @bar

newFoo = new NewFoo 'a foo'
console.log newFoo.getFoo()
console.log newFoo.history
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically doing that with Mixin :

```
class Mixin
  constructor:->
    super
```

if you call `new Mixin();` you'll get an error. You cant call super on a constructor that doesnt extend anything.

mixOf function doesnt fix that,it just copies methods from other objects and yields a class.

Comment: I see, so is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: sure, you could apply all mixin constructor functions in the Mixed constructor.